# Split cell into 3 cells in latex

Tags: latex, row, multiple-columns, cell

I tried to make a table and I got to this, I can't go to the final table
I left in a link the images of what it really can do and what I can't do

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|llll|}
\cline{2-5}
                         & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{EigenFaces}                                          \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ID da face} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Algoritmo} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Classificada como} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Confiança} 
& 
Tempo de processamento (s) \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and give somethin like that [image: image of table]
but i want something like that: [image: table i want]

i want each row with 3 cells from beginning at the end, but i cant understand the multicolumn with multirow

Comment: Don't try to split cells, merge the others instead

Comment: (and please do keep away from these terrible online table generators. The code they produce is really awful with all these interfering multicolumns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to split cells, merge the other cells instead. This is particularly easy with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={lllll},
  vlines,
  hlines,    
  vline{1} = {1}{wd=0pt},
  hline{1} = {1}{wd=0pt},
}
 & \SetCell[c=4]{halign=c} EigenFaces \\
ID da face & Algoritmo & Classificada como & Confiança & Tempo de processamento (s)\\
\SetCell[r=3]{} 0 & & & &\\
 & & & &\\ 
 & & & &\\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]